# How to get SHA1 fingerprints from p12 certificate?

Tags: java, android, command-line, sha

In order to get the keys of my  Android project, Google requires SHA1 fingerprint.
Offered this command: keytool-list-v-keystore mystore.keystore

I went through different options, but always in an error Illegal option: Files
keytool:-list [OPTION] ...

For example my command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -storepass mypass -list -v -keystore C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\android.p12
```

If i set p12 file in root (c:) then i get another error - Invalid keystore format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For p12 format (PKCS12) use option `-storetype PKCS12`.

For example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass 123456
```

For keystore/certificate inspection & manipulation i recommend GUI tool [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) (formerly: KeyToolGUI). [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portecleinstall/) is convenient windows installer.

Comment: Works on Mac as well via Terminal. ;)

Answer (score 24):

This can also be done with OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <my pkcs12 file>.p12 -nodes -passin pass:<passphrase, or blank> |openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint
```

Comment: I'd add -md5 after -fingerprint. Beside that works ok.

Comment: This and the accepted answer end up returning different fingerprints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Android Studio**. You can get fastly the **SHA1 certificate fingerprint** (**debug,release... all Build Types!!**) through Gradle Tasks:

> signingReport

SHA1 is shown in **Messages Logs**

**Android Plugin** (configured in the gradle app) creates a **debug** mode **for default**. 
File route to keystore:  *HOME/.android/debug.keystore*

I recommend attach debug.keystore to build.gradle. To do this put a file debug.keystore to a app folder.

Extra: If you want creates for release, put a file release.keystore to a app folder. (This example uses the same debug.keystore)